# Regexkitlite rejected at AppStore. What else can be used?

Tags: iphone, ios, regexkitlite

I am creating an application wherein I need to verify correct email format, for which I am using **Regexkitlite**. Although I works fine, but on spending some time on Google I [learnt](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Jun/msg00564.html) that it is no longer accepted on AppStore.

If this is so, what else can be used which is acceptable on AppStore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this in lots of apps that are currently on the app store.

```
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

    if([emailTest evaluateWithObject:email])
    {
         //email valid
    }
    else
    {
        //email not valid
    }
```